# How to comunicate 2 FeatureModule in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I have 2 feattures modules, one called navbarModule where I built all navbar(sidebar,footerbar,topbar) and I have another called userModule that has all user funcionality, when I do since any navbar menu [routerLink]="['/user']", it doesnt work,My navbarModule has not a routing, I just added all modules to tha app-routing.module, so how can I comunicate my navbarmenu with a specific module?

Comment: You need to import RouterModule at your userModule to use router events.

Comment: My userMOdule have a routing with routes define, the module that has not routing is navBarmodule and when I had a RouterModule doesnt work

Comment: this is my nabvarModule definition

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NavbarComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    FooterComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NewsModule,
    RouterModule

  ],
  exports:[
    NavbarComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ]
})
export class NavbarModule { }